# WordPress Settings validation messages are shown twice

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm adding a pretty basic (I feel) implementation of settings page validation for my WordPress plugin and it does work, but the error messages are shown twice.  I stepped through my code and the calls to `add_settings_error` are only executed once.

```
<?php

class Example_plugin_Settings {
    private $example_plugin_settings_options;
    private $settings_options_name;

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'example_plugin_settings_add_plugin_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'example_plugin_settings_page_init' ) );
        $this->settings_options_name = 'example_plugin_options';
    }

    public function example_plugin_settings_add_plugin_page() {
        add_options_page(
            'Example-Plugin Connector Settings', // page_title
            'Example-Plugin', // menu_title
            'manage_options', // capability
            'example-plugin-connector-settings', // menu_slug
            array( $this, 'example_plugin_settings_create_admin_page' ) // function
        );
    }

    public function example_plugin_settings_create_admin_page() {
        $this->example_plugin_settings_options = get_option( 'example_plugin_options' ); ?>

        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Example-Plugin Connector Settings</h2>
            <p>Set up additional portals/currencies to be used with WooCommerce Currency Switcher (WOOCS).  Enter a comma-delimited list of portals, then the corresponding comma-delimited list of currencies that those portals support.</p>
            <?php settings_errors(); ?>

            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php
                settings_fields( 'example_plugin_settings_option_group' );
                do_settings_sections( 'example-plugin-connector-settings-admin' );
                submit_button();
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php }

    public function example_plugin_settings_page_init() {
        register_setting(
            'example_plugin_settings_option_group', // option_group
            $this->settings_options_name, // option_name
            array( $this, 'example_plugin_settings_sanitize' ) // sanitize_callback
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'example_plugin_settings_setting_section', // id
            'Settings', // title
            array( $this, 'example_plugin_settings_section_info' ), // callback
            'example-plugin-connector-settings-admin' // page
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'portals', // id
            'Portals', // title
            array( $this, 'portals_callback' ), // callback
            'example-plugin-connector-settings-admin', // page
            'example_plugin_settings_setting_section' // section
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'currencies', // id
            'Currencies', // title
            array( $this, 'currencies_callback' ), // callback
            'example-plugin-connector-settings-admin', // page
            'example_plugin_settings_setting_section' // section
        );
    }

    public function example_plugin_settings_sanitize($input) {
        $sanitary_values = array();
        if ( isset( $input['portals'] ) ) {
            if ( '' == $input['portals'] ) {
                $input['portals'] = '';
                add_settings_error(
                    $this->settings_options_name,
                    'portals',
                    'Portals is a required field.',
                    'error'
                );
            } else {
                $sanitary_values['portals'] = sanitize_text_field( trim( $input['portals'] ) );
            }
        }

        if ( isset( $input['currencies'] ) ) {
            if ( '' == $input['currencies'] ) {
                $input['currencies'] = '';
                add_settings_error(
                    $this->settings_options_name,
                    'currencies',
                    'Currencies is a required field.',
                    'error'
                );
            } else {
                $sanitary_values['currencies'] = sanitize_text_field( trim( $input['currencies'] ) );
            }
        }

        return $sanitary_values;
    }

    public function example_plugin_settings_section_info() {

    }

    public function portals_callback() {
        printf(
            '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="example_plugin_options[portals]" id="portals" value="%s">',
            isset( $this->example_plugin_settings_options['portals'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->example_plugin_settings_options['portals']) : ''
        );
    }

    public function currencies_callback() {
        printf(
            '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="example_plugin_options[currencies]" id="currencies" value="%s">',
            isset( $this->example_plugin_settings_options['currencies'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->example_plugin_settings_options['currencies']) : ''
        );
    }

}
if ( is_admin() )
    $example_plugin_settings = new Example_plugin_Settings();
```

[image: duplicate errors]

Answer (score 4):

It seems the problem is the line `<?php settings_errors(); ?>`.  I got the base code from the [WordPress Options Page Generator](https://jeremyhixon.com/tool/wordpress-option-page-generator/) but maybe the code is outdated and that line is now redundant with newer versions of WordPress?  I'm not sure.

Comment: Im my case, i had to call this line in order to be able to even show the error message. Without this, it don't even appears.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because WordPress is already calling `settings_errors()`, so you don't need to add it again.

It is important to notice that `settings_errors()` is only included by default in some wp-admin pages: Everything under **Settings** seems to include it.

This is a common issue. You may find [more information about it here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31000).

If we check the [documentation for `settings_errors()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/settings_errors/) we find the following:

> This is called automatically after a settings page based on the
> Settings API is submitted. Errors should be added during the
> validation callback function for a setting defined in
> register_setting() .

This is telling us that if we are using the Settings API for our settings page, we don't need to manually include `settings_errors()` as they are already calling it for us.

In other words, if you are using `register_setting()` in your page, you don't need to use `settings_errors()`. Using it in this situation will cause getting duplicated admin notices. That is, at least, in theory.